# Wordpress, Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_wp_version_compatible()

Tags: wordpress

I was migrating a WordPress website into an old one with a old version of WordPress by using WP Migrator all in one and by mistake I refreshed the page at 69% of loading so the transfer shouldn't be completed. Now I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_wp_version_compatible() in /web/htdocs/www.euronutspa.com/home/wp-content/plugins/coblocks/includes/class-block-patterns.php on line 29

As I understand I probably updated the plugin "coblock" and now it's giving issues with the version of WordPress. How should I fix this? I cant go in my admin page anymore!

Comment: Do you have FTP or cPanel access?

Comment: yes I do, I have the access

Comment: You can try to disable the plugins via FTP: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/360022275731/how-to-deactivate-wordpress-plugins-for-troubleshooting (Try the second option)